# Count rows of a DataGridView where a cell value is less than another cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview, count

i want to count all rows of a DataGridView where a cell value is less than another cell value. In my code all rows where cell value1 (int a) is less than cell value2 (int b) get inked. But i don't really find a way to count the rows. Right now my int counter would give out: 1 which can't be true. I think i will need something like dgvArticleStockInfo.RowsCount(a <= b) but i didn't find a way to make that work. Any help is appreciated :)

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvArticleStockInfo.Rows)
            {
                int counter = 0;

                int a = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
                if (a <= b)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(144, 238, 144);
                    panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(144, 238, 144);
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,106,106);
                    panel2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,106,106);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you initialize your `counter` in *every* iteration and put it's value to `0`. It goes to your if part and increase it's value and it will be `1`. But after your next iteration, you initialize it to zero *again* and increase it.

Initialize your `counter` *before* your foreach loop and you should be fine.

```
int counter = 0;
int a = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvArticleStockInfo.Rows)
{
     if (a <= b)
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(144, 238, 144);
         panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(144, 238, 144);
         counter++;
     }
     else
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,106,106);
         panel2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,106,106);
     }
}
```

But more important than that, you could solve this problem with an easy debugging operation. I suggest you to read those articles to improve your debugging skills.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173083%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
- http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/

Comment: yep to initialize the counter before the foreach loop starts solved the problem (idk why i did not recognized that). Thank you :)